# JSF 2 h:message in composite component can't find id of input

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have the following working code:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Name:" for="nameField"/>
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText id="nameField" value="${bean.name}" required="true" />
    <t:message for="nameField"
        detailFormat="!" tooltip="true" errorClass="errorMessage"
        infoClass="infoMessage" fatalClass="fatalMessage"
        warnClass="warningMessage"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Now I'm trying to wrap the message component into a composite component that looks like this:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="for" required="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <t:message for="#{cc.attrs.for}"
                detailFormat="!" tooltip="true"
                errorClass="errorMessage" infoClass="infoMessage"
                fatalClass="fatalMessage" warnClass="warningMessage"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

With the reference implementation (2.0.3) I get the following exception:

```
Jul 8, 2011 10:59:13 AM org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlMessageRendererBase renderMessage
SEVERE: Could not render Message. Unable to find component 'nameField' (calling findComponent on component 'simplePersonSearchForm:j_idt89:j_idt100'). If the provided id was correct, wrap the message and its component into an h:panelGroup or h:panelGrid.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.createMetaRuleset(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:247)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:123)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.setAttributes(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyNextHandler(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:178)
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with `<h:message>`. I'd consider it to be a bug in Tomahawk's implementation.

So you have 2 options:

1. Replace it with `<h:message>`.
2. Report the issue to Tomahawk guys and wait for them to get it fixed.

Comment: h:message also doesn't seem to work,.. I don't get a stacktrace but the message also doesn't show. If I replace the composite component with just the h:message (or the t:message) the message does show.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I have used Mojarra 2.1.1. There, now you know it as well.

Comment: Yeps, I've tried different versions and am currently using 2.1.2, where it doesn't seem to work. But I'll investigate a bit further after my vacation.

I'll also file a bug report with tomahawk.